# Can't close iterator once DB connection is closed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, iterator, database-connection

The following problem took place when I started using Intellij IDEA. 
In Eclipse everything works fine and iterator closes.

I suppose this is an configuration issue. What solutions could you suggest?

SiteFeatureData class select method snippet:

```
    Connection dbconn = null;
    try{
        dbconn = ConnCacheImpl.getConnection();
        ctx = Data.getContext(dbconn);
        etx = new ExecutionContext();
        #sql [ctx,etx] iter = {
            SELECT id, ...
        };
    if ( iter.next() ) {
            populate( iter, ...
                    , ctx.getConnection()
                    );
        } 
    }finally{
        try{
            dbconn.close();
            returnContext(ctx,etx,iter);
        } catch(SQLException ex){};
        ctx = null;
        etx = null;
        iter = null;
    }
```

Data class returnContext method:

```
protected static void returnContext(DefaultContext ctx
                                   ,ExecutionContext etx
                                   ,ResultSetIterImpl iter) throws SQLException{
    if(iter != null){
        iter.close();  // PROBLEM IS HERE
    }
    if(etx != null){
        etx.close();
    }
    if(ctx != null){
        ctx.close(ConnectionContext.KEEP_CONNECTION);
    }
}


Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getStmtCacheSize(Unknown Source)
    at sqlj.runtime.ref.OraRTResultSet.close(OraRTResultSet.java:1018)
    at sqlj.runtime.ref.ResultSetIterImpl.close(ResultSetIterImpl.java:187)
    at com.softdesign.persistence.Data.returnContext(Data.java:60)
    at com.requestcom.geofire.domain.data.SiteFeatureData.select(SiteFeatureData.java:2326)
    at com.softdesign.persistence.Persistent.exists(Persistent.java:343)
    at com.softdesign.persistence.Persistent.exists(Persistent.java:326)
    at com.requestcom.geofire.context.ServletRequestContext.getSiteFeature(ServletRequestContext.java:3976)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.doInvoke(UberspectImpl.java:395)
    at org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl$VelMethodImpl.invoke(UberspectImpl.java:384)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.parser.node.ASTMethod.execute(ASTMethod.java:173)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The connection is closed: The connection is closed
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:473)
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:457)
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.JDBCConnectionProxyFactory.invoke(JDBCConnectionProxyFactory.java:255)
    ... 53 more
```

Comment: Do you still use the same server? (e.g. Tomcat 7.0.... ?) There could be differences there. Also, you can just mitigate it, by checking dbconn.isOpen() before closing the connection.

Comment: Yes, i use the same server. But in Eclipse everything works.

Comment: That.... I really don't know :( these IDE's are pretty magic boxes, each with their own special features...

Answer (score 1):

At the trace can be seen that you are calling OraRTResultSet.close() which is an implementation of java.sql.ResultSet.close() after you have called Connection.close()
That will always raise an exception.
You must close the ResultSet before closing the connection.
So flip lines

```
returnContext(ctx,etx,iter);
dbconn.close();
```

Comment: I got it. But I have no problem using Eclipse. How could you explain why I have a problem only with IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

You need check if the connection is closed before you call iter.close() method.

```
if(iter != null && !iter.isClosed()){
    iter.close(); 
}
```

And you can try close your iterator before your DBConnection. This should solve the problem too.

Comment: I got it. But I have no problem using Eclipse. How could you explain why I have a problem only with IDEA?

Comment: Well, the try { } catch (SQLException) { } inside finally { } is pretty dangerous. According to java.sql.Connection spec " If the close method is called and there is an active transaction, the results are implementation-defined." Therefore, one legitimate behaviour of dbconn.close(); if you call it with an open ResultSet could be to throw a SQLException which would be catched and you would end up having a connection leak. Maybe the driver implementation that you are using with Intellij IDEA is different from the one you use with Eclipse and that is why you see the difference in behaviour.

Comment: I use the same driver implementation which is defined in context.xml. 

factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl" type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"     connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"

Comment: Even if you are using the same connection pool,  your JDBC driver could still be different. The driver is loaded by caling Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") or DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver()) Check that you do not have different .jar files containing the class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

Comment: I use the same JDBC driver. I'm totally confused. The same examples:
dbconn.close();
returnContext(ctx,etx,iter); I can see in the whole application and everything works fine on prod and locally using Eclipse.